# Will an AC voltmeter show deflection if connected across a pure inductor in an AC LCR circuit?

Tags: ac, inductor, voltmeter

I'm asking this on behalf of one of my classmates.

My thoughts:
It will, as if there is current flowing backwards, there needs to be an EMF developed, and if there is no voltage drop, Kirchhoff's laws will be violated.

Answer (score 1):

$$V=L\frac{di}{dt}$$ Right? So if there's a changing current there will be a voltage across the inductor.  Assuming the voltage is within the detection capabilities of your meter you should see the meter reflect the voltage across the inductor, minus any I*R drops that are in the path.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let my classmate kno, if he has any questions, can I ask them on his behalf?

Comment: No rule here against asking questions on someone else's behalf.

Comment: Thanks! Again, on his behalf it will show $I_{RMS}$ * $X_L$ right?

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever what the meter reads depends on the meter- If it is a true RMS meter AND the signal is within its measurement bandwidth it should read the RMS voltage across the inductor.  If not, the meter may show a voltage but it might not be accurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!